# how to parse the remainder: [0] on google-app-engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, arrays

my code is :

```
class demo(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        a=[[1,2,3],[3,6,9]]
        self.render_template('map/a.html',{'geo':a})
```

and  the html is :

```
{% for i in geo %}
        <p><a href="{{ i[0] }}">{{ i[0]}}</a></p>
{% endfor%}
```

and  the error is :

```
raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Could not parse the remainder: %s" % token[upto:]
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: [0]
```

so what should i do  .

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the page to show the first item of each list:

```
{% for i in geo %}
  <p><a href="{{ i.0 }}">{{ i.0 }}</a></p>
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: I love you man I wasted an hour trying to figure out why the hell {{list_item[0]}} was not working

Comment: Glad to be of service :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean you need to parse the remainder; it's saying the template engine tried to parse your `i[0]`, understood `i`, but was unable to parse the remainder of the string, `[0]`. It looks like you can't index arrays that way; you may need to do something like this:

```
{% for i,j,k in geo %}
    <p><a href="{{ i }}">{{ i}}</a></p>
{% endfor%}
```